# Pi Zero copy files from pc to mounted usb drive

Tags: usb, pi-zero, mount

I am new to pi programming and my searches for this have been fruitless. I am looking to connect a usb drive to my pi zero to use as permanent external storage.  When I plug my pi into my pc via otg cable, I want the pi to appear as a storage device that I can copy images, mp3s and mp4s to. Just like when you plug an mp3 player in and copy files to it.

Comment: so, your searches didn't come up with [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive/) - at first glance it appears to be what you want

Comment: what did you search for?